# When passing useState as prop Datagrid stops working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I have a strange problem when I edit my DataGrid.I want to keep track of all my edited rows so I created a useState for that. If I create the useState directly in the DataTable-component everything works as expected and I can edit the Width and Height columns and they also gets added to the useState.
But I realized that I needed to place the useState in the parent App component instead so that I could process the results from a buttonHandler in the App component. When I create a new UseState in the App comonent and pass it as props to the DataTable component the edited row still gets added correctly to the useState. But for some reason the edited DataTable row reverts back to the previous value directly after the edit is done.

Does anyone understand why this happens ?

```
App.jsx
function App() {
  const [labelsTest, setLabelsTest] = useState([])
  const [labelsProd, setLabelsProd] = useState([])
  const [selectedLabelsets, setSelectedLabelsets] = useState([])
  const [currentSelectedLabel, setcurrentSelectedLabel] = useState({})
  const [rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState("All")
  const [x, setX] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    const fetchLabels = async () => {
      try {
        await getLabels(setLabelsTest, "TEST")
        await getLabels(setLabelsProd, "PROD")

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Could not fetch labels")
      }
    }
    fetchLabels()

  }, [])

  const filterData = (data) => {
    let dataCopy = data.map(entry => ({ id: entry.LABELDESIGNID, ...entry }))
    return selectedFilter !== "All" ? dataCopy.filter(l => l.UNITTYPE == selectedFilter) : dataCopy
  }

  const updateProdLabels = async () => {
    console.log("Update");
    await getLabels(setLabelsProd, "PROD", true)
  }

  const moveButtonHandler = async () => {

    await updateLabelDesignRevInProd(selectedLabelsets)
    await getLabels(setLabelsProd, "PROD")
  }

  const applyButtonHandler = async (rows) => {
   for (const row of rows) {
      await updateLabelDimensionsInProd(row)
   }
    

  }

  return (
    <>

      {labelsProd.length != 0 && labelsTest.length != 0 &&
        <>
          <Container

            maxWidth="xl"
            sx={{ backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5' }}>
            <Box sx={{ height: '100vh', backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5' }}>
              <Typography variant="h4" component="h2" margin='20px 0px 10px 0px'>
                Labelset som hittades i Test
              </Typography>

              <div>
                <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
                  <Select onChange={e => setSelectedFilter(e.target.value)} value={selectedFilter}>
                    <MenuItem value="All">All</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Inserts">Inserts</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Tools">Tools</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Round Tools">Round Tools</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
                  <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => updateProdLabels()}>Refresh</Button>
                </FormControl>

              </div>

              <div >
                <DataTable data={filterData(labelsTest)} {...{ selectedLabelsets, setSelectedLabelsets, currentSelectedLabel, setcurrentSelectedLabel, rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel, x, setX }} env={"TEST"} />

              </div>
              <Typography variant="h4" component="h2" margin='20px 0px 10px 0px'>
                Labelset som hittades i Prod
              </Typography>
              <div >
                <DataTable data={filterData(labelsProd)} checkboxSelection={false} currentSelectedLabel={currentSelectedLabel} selectedLabelsets={selectedLabelsets} env={"PROD"} x={x} setX={setX} />
              </div>
              <Box
              sx={{ display: 'flex',justifyContent:'space-between' }}
              >
                <Button
                  variant='contained'
                  sx={{ mt: 2 }}
                  onClick={moveButtonHandler}
                >Move to Prod</Button>
                <Button
                  variant='contained'
                  sx={{ mt: 2 }}
                  onClick={applyButtonHandler}
                >Apply changes</Button>
              </Box>


            </Box>
          </Container>
        </> || <h1>Could not fetch any labels</h1>

      }
    </>


  );
}

export default App;
```

```
DataTable.jsx
...
import '../components/DataTable.css'

const columns = [
    { field: 'LABELDESIGNID', headerName: 'Label Id', width: 70 },
    { field: 'LABELDESIGNNAME', headerName: 'Labelname', width: 120 },
    { field: 'WIDTH', headerName: 'Width', width: 70, type: 'number', editable: true },
    { field: 'HEIGHT', headerName: 'Height', width: 70, type: 'number', editable: true },
    { field: 'LABELDESIGNREVID', headerName: 'Rev Id', width: 100 },
    { field: 'DESIGNERID', headerName: 'Designer', width: 100 },
    { field: 'REVCOMMENT', headerName: 'Comment', width: 650 },
    { field: 'DATEAPPROVED', headerName: 'Date Approved', width: 200 },
];

export default function DataTable({ data, env, selectedLabelsets, setSelectedLabelsets, currentSelectedLabel, setcurrentSelectedLabel, setRowSelectionModel, checkboxSelection = true, x, setX }) {
    
    const [editedRows, setEditedRows] = useState([])

    const handleRowClick = (params) => {
        if (env === "TEST") {
            setSelectedLabelsets(params.map(id => ({ id: parseInt(id), labeldesignname: data.find(d => d.LABELDESIGNID === parseInt(id)).LABELDESIGNNAME, revid: data.find(d => d.LABELDESIGNID === parseInt(id)).CURRENTLABELDESIGNREVID })))
        }
    }

    const handleUpdate = async (updatedRow, originalRow) => {

        if (env === "PROD" && JSON.stringify(originalRow) !== JSON.stringify(updatedRow)) {

            console.log("UpdatedRow");
            console.log(updatedRow);

            console.log("OriginalRow");
            console.log(originalRow);
           // setEditedRows([...editedRows, updatedRow])
            setX([...x, updatedRow])
           
        }
        console.log("Returning Updated Row");
        return updatedRow


    }

    const handleRowEditStop = (event) => {
        if (event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ height: 500, width: '100%' }}>

            <DataGrid
                rows={data}
                columns={columns}
                processRowUpdate={(updatedRow, originalRow) =>
                    handleUpdate(updatedRow, originalRow)
                }
                sx={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFEFD' }}
                initialState={{
                    pagination: {
                        paginationModel: { autoPageSize: true },
                    },
                }}
                onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
                checkboxSelection={checkboxSelection}
                onRowSelectionModelChange={handleRowClick}
                onProcessRowUpdateError={(error => console.error(error))}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Tried passing useState as props and expected everything to function as when the useState was locally declared.But the edited rows gets reverted directly after edit.

Comment: I think I understand why my datatable values vas reverting after edit. I think that when I passed a usestate using the props the entire DataGrid component was rerendered on each edit. That made the DataGrid component refresh with the original data in the same way as when I first launched the application.